# PHP file_get_contents сайт на HTTPS не дает открыть HTTP

Tags: php

Сам мой сайт находится и открывается только по HTTPS.
Из кода этого сайта эта функция gile_get_contents может получить только сайты на https, если указать любой сайт на http - пишет в лог ошибки (refused, not reacheable и т.д.) и возвращает пустоту.

На сервере апач, нгинкс, isp панель. Пхп пробовал любой от 5.3 до 7.1 - результат один и тот же, только https получает.

Где это настроить, чтобы можно было и http получать?
У других хостеров все ОК, только у одного такая трабла и не могут найти в чем проблема.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-to-work-with-https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась весьма странной: аппаратный (не программный даже) сбой. Оборудование Cisco у хостера не перезагружалось больше года и в результате стало давать такой сбой (не пропускать трафик http с https ресурсов). Я не вдавался в детали проблемы, но хостер перезагрузил оборудование и всё заработало (и хотсер же написал мне краткое описание этой проблемы в тикете, но несколько дней никто не мог понять, что и где не так).

Answer (score 0):

проверьте работают ли те же запросы на CURL аналоге?

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

если нет, то скорее всего проблема в сетевых настройках, firewall.

Comment: Спасибо за то,что обратили внимание на вопрос. проблема оказалась куда хитрее и прозаичнее - аппаратный (не программный даже) сбой. Оборудование Cisco у хостера не перезагружалось больше года и в результате стало давать такой сбой (не пропускать трафик http с https ресурсов). Я не вдавался в детали проблемы, но хостер перезагрузил оборудование и всё заработало (и хотсер же написал мне краткое описание этой проблемы в тикете, но несколько дней никто не мог понять, что и где не так).